# How to use spaces and periods in an Ansible playbook windows path:?

Tags: windows, ansible, path, yaml, space

I have a playbook that installs an app on a Windows test server.  Here is part of the yaml code.

```
- name: Install app
  win_package:
    path: C:\Temp\someDIR\APP.msi
    state: present
```

This works.  Unfortunately, the DIR and APP have spaces and periods in the actual path.
Testing further I found

```
path: C:\Temp\some DIR\APP.msi        works
path: C:\Temp\someDIR.123\APP.msi     works
path: 'C:\Temp\some D I R\APP.msi'    works
```

but putting the spaces and period together doesn't work.

```
path: C:\Temp\some D I R.123\APP.msi      fails
path: 'C:\Temp\some D I R.123\APP.msi'    fails
```

Suggestions?

TIA

Comment: Hi David Hill welcome to SO. Please don't stop typing when writing "doesn't work," because the universe of ways it **can** fail is infinite, the number of ways it *did fail* for you are finite and known only to you. Please read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) section. Good luck

Comment: We run Ansible Tower version 2.9.18.  The error is the same for the two failures shown previously.  The error message from the task that failed is


fatal: [W2k19TestVM]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "the file at the local path C:\Temp\some APP.123\SomeAPP.msi cannot be reached", "reboot_required": false}

Comment: Please don't add that info inside a comments, [edit] your question.

Comment: Have you tried `path: '"C:\Temp\some D I R.123\APP.msi"'`?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your patience and suggestions.  @Zeitounator, your suggestion path: **'"C:\Temp... "'** gave an error stating product_id: is required.  Adding the product_id: gave an error stating it couldn't find the file in the local path, showing the local path with double backslash instead of single backslash.  This reminded me using double quotes allows escaping characters.  Here what finally worked.  **path: "C:\\Temp\\some D I R.123\\APP.msi"** .